# Regex to exclude a pattern in filename

Tags: javascript, regex, filenames, regex-lookarounds

My current pattern is:

```
/\.(scss|js|jsx)$/
```

I want to exclude files that end with "-test.js"

I've tried:

```
/(?!-test)\.(scss|js|jsx)$/
```

but it's not working.

Comment: What language/environment will you be running this pattern in?  Can you offer a few sample inputs and your expected result for each?  Please post your language specific regex implementation.

Comment: javascript,  filename blabla.js should match, blabla-test.js should not match. everything with .scss and .jsx should match. used for webpack config

Answer (score 2):

As JS does not support lookbehind, you can do `^(?!.*-test\.js$).*\.(js|scss|jsx)$` as a workaround.

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/upQVte/6)

```js
var testFiles = ['p-test.js',
  'q-test.scss',
  'r-test.jsx',
  'p.js',
  'q.scss',
  'r.jsx',
  'sadadf-testddd.js'
];
var myRegexp = /^(?!.*-test\.js$).*\.(js|scss|jsx)$/g;
testFiles.forEach(function(file) {
  var match = file.match(myRegexp)
  console.log(file + " : " + (match ? 'matches' : 'does not match'));
})
```

Comment: thx this works, but not perfectly: the exact antipattern should be "*-test.js", so no space other characters between "test" and ".js" and the minus is a part of the pattern  https://regex101.com/r/upQVte/4

Comment: @jeff Sorry about that. Updated my answer just in case.

Comment: thanks, "sadadf-testddd.js" is still a wrong negative

Answer (score 1):

`js|jsx` can be refined/sped-up by using: `jsx?`.
`scss` can be sped-up by using `scs{2}`.
Putting shorter "alternatives" before longer ones will improve speed. `(jsx?|scs{2})`

Patterns:

```
/^(.(?!-test\.js$))+\.(jsx?|scs{2})$/
```

or in nearly half the steps, due to removed capture group:

```
/^(?!.*-test\.js$).*\.(jsx?|scs{2})$/
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gakqbO/1)

Test cases:

```
a-test.js      #fail
b-test.scss    #pass 
c-test.jsx     #pass
d.js           #pass
e.scss         #pass
f.jsx          #pass
g-testg.js     #pass
h-testh.scss   #pass
i-testi.jsx    #pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
/^([a-z0-9-_](?!-test\.))+\.(scss|js|jsx)$/
```

None of the characters of the filename should be followed by `-test.`.

Comment: I've just fixed it.